# OpenMDAO>=1.X.X not enforcing upper and lower values?

Tags: openmdao

Is it intentional that upper and lower values are no longer enforced in OpenMDAO>=1.X.X?  I would have thought that the example below should give an error.  I could be wrong, but I thought that OpenMDAO<=1 did fail when a component was evaluated outside the ranges of its inputs variables.

```
from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Component, Problem, Group

class ExampleComponent(Component):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleComponent, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('x', val=0.0, lower=-2., upper=2.)
        self.add_param('y', val=0.0, lower=-2., upper=2.)

        self.add_output('f_xy', shape=1)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        unknowns['f_xy'] = params['x'] ** 2 + params['y'] ** 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    top = Problem()

    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 3.0))
    root.add('p2', IndepVarComp('y', -4.0))
    root.add('p', ExampleComponent())

    root.connect('p1.x', 'p.x')
    root.connect('p2.y', 'p.y')

    top.setup()
    top.run()

    print(top['p.f_xy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer is... sort of.

In OpenMDAO <= 1.x we used to strictly enforce the given bounds values at all times. However, we found that this caused some problems in the common situation where you set a bound on the variable, but its really "soft". By that I mean that you don't mind if it exceeds the bounds during convergence but must be satisfied in the end.

So in 1.x we treat the bounds information differently. The newton solver strictly respects the bounds by preventing the update step from violating them. The drivers have access to the bounds data and can do what they like with them. But the framework does not throw an error just because you set a value outside the bounds.

If you would like this behavior on one of your components, I suggest you sub-class Component and modify the [_sys_solve_nonlinear](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/4a805881fdca52b8ec061c3779025aea5d553c09/openmdao/core/component.py#L593) and [_sys_apply_nonlinear](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/4a805881fdca52b8ec061c3779025aea5d553c09/openmdao/core/component.py#L535) methods to do some bounds checking and throw an error if any of the parameters/unknowns violate the given bounds.